# Angular CLI 'serve' status code 404 CURL (but loading in browser)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm building a new app using angular2 within Electron, I am a fan of automating every single step of the process. Because of that I am using a few NPM scripts to serve/ build/ build(prod) and package within the Electron wrapper. The serve version is having some issues.

I've already configured Electron in such a way that the NPM script decides what to load into the view (dist/index.html or http://localhost:4200/).

The custom `electron:serve` command/script basically runs Electron and Angular CLI simultaneously, the Electron process must wait on the Angular CLI to be initialized, therefor I have built in the NPM package `wait-on` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on). This workflow should normally work (I've done this with React (CRA)).

The `wait-on` package pings the specified target every 250ms and waits for a status code somewhere in the 200 range (in case of HTTP(S)). The problem I'm facing is that the server running within the Angular CLI (`ng serve`) keeps returning a 404 when running (keep in mind, this is a fresh project generated with the Angular CLI).

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:4200/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 140
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 08:44:33 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

It can't be my false configuration, it can however be lack of configuration. Is this problem even solvable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pinging the HEAD HTTP status of `http://localhost:4200/` you can use `http-get://localhost:4200/`, this will get the status code from an a GET HTTP status. This will – as it does in the browser – return HTTP status code 2XX.